# Wordpress website stopped sending emails altogether

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

i have a wordpress/woocommerce shop website and as of two days ago it's email system has completely broken
emails stopped sending from my website altogether (new order / cancelled orders, receipt for customers, contact forms, newsletter sign-ups, etc

Comment: FYI: Stack Overflow is not a job posting board.

Comment: Is there an error message? Maby ask your hoster.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking to hire someone to solve their problem.

Comment: Why not just help the guy solve his problem here; then it is available for others searching for a similar problem!

Answer (score 0):

First thing you need to work out is why has it stopped sending mail.

Has the codebase changed recently?

Has the server been upgraded or changed?

Has your site been compromised?

In a situation like this I would recommend initially making sure that your server has not been blacklisted, enter your web address into http://mxtoolbox.com to run scans across the major blacklists.

If that comes up clear, next you need to check your forms in a browser by submitting them. During this, keep open an Inspector program such as Firebug, the 'Network' panel will detail any network requests made and let you see if they are sent to the server and if they are received and processed by the server.